# What is wrong with my implementation of FIR filter?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, octave

I tried to implement an FIR filter to remove a 60 Hz noise from my ECG data with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7ypfE5TQK0 as the reference. But somehow my signal after applying the filter is not right.

From the MIT-BIH database, they state

"The analog outputs of the playback unit were filtered to limit analog-to-digital converter (ADC) saturation and for anti-aliasing, using a passband from 0.1 to 100 Hz relative to real time, well beyond the lowest and highest frequencies recoverable from the recordings. The bandpass-filtered signals were digitized at 360 Hz per signal relative to real time using hardware constructed at the MIT Biomedical Engineering Center and at the BIH Biomedical Engineering Laboratory. The sampling frequency was chosen to facilitate implementations of 60 Hz (mains frequency) digital notch filters in arrhythmia detectors. Since the recorders were battery-powered, most of the 60 Hz noise present in the database arose during playback."

```
fsample = 360; %sampling frequency 
fnyquist = fsample/2; % nyquist frequency
fnoise = 60; %noise is 60Hz

fnornoiseL =(fnoise-1)/fnyquist % normalized noise frequency lower bounds
fnornoiseH =(fnoise+1)/fnyquist %normalized noise frequency higher bound

b = fir1(100,[fnornoiseL fnornoiseH],'stop');
y2 =filter(b,1,y);
disp("hello");
plot(y2);
```

y is the signal in the form y = [a b c d ....]

when i do

```
plot(y)
```

[image]

but running `plot(y2)` gives

[image]

Comment: How long is your signal `y`? Has it 100 samples, which is the same length as your FIR? Why did you choose your FIR in this way? Nevertheless, checking your filter with `freqz` you will see that it has the response you want. However the problem you have is the settling time of your filter. Hance it is no suprise that have to wait a certain time until you see a meanigful output, for this read [Transient Response, Steady State, and Decay](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/Transient_Response_Steady_State.html)

Comment: One way to overcome this problem is to input a longer signal an cut the valid-processed samples out or you use a filter with a different settling time/ characteristics (a shorter FIR or IIR).

Comment: @Irreducible I am not really from an electrical engineering background so I am sorry if it sounds rudimentary, but how do I implement a shorter FIR?

Comment: @Irreducible I will give that link a shot

Comment: @Irreducible the link you provided has a link to a function "designfilt" in matlab but I'm using octave. I got the error "the 'fdesign' function belongs to the signal package from Octave Forge
but has not yet been implemented."

Comment: Have you considered to change the search to octave instead of matlab??? You would get that: [eg](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/filtering-50hz-using-a-notch-filter-in-matlab).

Comment: @Irreducible sorry for my blunder but thank you so much for your time. The reason I had both matlab and octave was I was desperate for a solution because nothing was working. I want to thank you so much for your time. I really appreciate it.